# Codeigniter--add “active” css class, how to apply on a link?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a url like this 
`http://localhost/bestbookfinder.com/viewallbooks/books/pgn/grid/6`

where:

**bestbookfinder.com**: Project name

**viewallbooks**      : class name

**books**             :function

**pgn**               :Constant Parameter

**grid**              :view type

**6**                 :pagination current page number

so now i am trying to read the above shown url and   to apply the CSS class with the following code, but unfortunately my code is not working. 
I think i am making mistake when i tried to read the url.

Please help me to solve this problem

```
<?php
if ( $this->uri->uri_string() == '/books/pgn/grid' )//i think mistake is here
 {
  echo "".anchor(base_url().'viewallbooks/books/pgn/grid/'.$this->uri->segment(5),'  Grid', array('id' => 'gridactive'))."";
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [codeigniter manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html) - `uri_string()` returns a string with the complete URI. So in your example that would be `"viewallbooks/books/pgn/grid/6"`.

Therefore `"viewallbooks/books/pgn/grid/6" != '/books/pgn/grid'`

Just do something like this:

```
if ($this->uri->segment(4) == "grid")
{
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($this->uri->segment(4) == 'grid'){
    //carry on
```